# Why does Jupyter Notebook stop working after a few seconds?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have a problem with Jupyter and can't find anything by someone with the same experience. When I start Jupyter Notebook, it only lasts for a few seconds until it freezes. Sometimes it happens in the command prompt before my browser is opened, most of the times when I'm navigating through my directories and sometimes, if it really wants to rub it in, when I've finally opened a notebook.

I've tried reinstalling both Jupyter and Anaconda, but that didn't help. I've also tried different versions Jupyter and Python. This is what I do:

```
conda env create -n myname python=3.6 pip
activate myname
conda install jupyter OR pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

I also tried installing from the Anaconda dashboard. Sometimes it works for a day and then a little later, I get the same problem again. The console also stops outputting data.

It doesn't seem to happen in the base environment.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Any logs, any output?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @AMC Unfortunately not. The console freezes as well.

Comment: @Prune I assume you mean because of the title. I adjusted it.

Comment: It's *really* hard for us to help without a reproducible context.  Otherwise, this is more suitable for SuperUser.

Comment: @Prune ??? It's a fresh install of Anaconda after which I executed the commands I mentioned above. Notebook just completely stops working after a few seconds. I really think there's no more I can tell about it. I'll wait a little and then I will probably check another forum as well.

Comment: Oof!  Yes, in that case, I *definitely* think that SuperUser is the right place for this.  In the meantime, I'm deleting my votes.